# startAdvertisingSet() api is not working as expected

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create a BLE server application using BLE5 advertisement api. AdvertisingSetCallback is success (onAdvertisingSetStarted), but I don't see my server device on client application.

```
private AdvertiseSettings buildAdvertiseSettings() {
    AdvertiseSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();
    settingsBuilder.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER);
    settingsBuilder.setTimeout(0);
    return settingsBuilder.build();
}

private AdvertiseData buildAdvertiseData() {
    AdvertiseData.Builder dataBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
    dataBuilder.addServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(Constants.HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID.toString()));
    dataBuilder.setIncludeDeviceName(true);
    return dataBuilder.build();
}

private void startAdvertising() {

        AdvertiseSettings settings = buildAdvertiseSettings();
        AdvertiseData data = buildAdvertiseData();

        if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser != null) {
            if (BLE5Support && bluetoothAdapter.isLe2MPhySupported() && bluetoothAdapter.isLeExtendedAdvertisingSupported()) {
                AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder parameters = (new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder())
                        .setLegacyMode(false)
                        .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_LOW)
                        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .setPrimaryPhy(BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_1M)
                        .setSecondaryPhy(BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_2M);

                mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters.build(), data, null, null, null, advertisingSetCallback);


            } else {
              
            mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Did you set bluetooth discoverable from your phone (server bluetooth) ?

Comment: Yes Ande, I am able to see my server device on client app if I use mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising() API